# Spring MVC fileupload, usually progress bar is done by Javascript?

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

Beginners alert....

This may seem like a very strange question to ask.... but I have been researching how to do file upload with Spring MVC framework.

I found a lot of example that uses apache common-io dependency.
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html

As I was researching further to implement progressListener.  I found this.... http://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-multi-file-upload-with-progress-bar/

Now, I always thought that the progress bar percentage is calculated by the server how much the file has been uploaded. So I thought we needed to implement a calculation in the controller where it returns like a percent of bytes being transfered... or bytes written to directory.

But from the 2nd link example, it seem that the Spring controller does not perform any calculation just writes the file to destination.

**So the question is...**

1. How does file transfer actually work...I can only assume from the example Spring controller wait until it receives the complete file before writing to server directory? Thats why to show progress bar we use javascript to calculate how much of the file has been transferred to server but not written?
2. Need a little help on understanding javascript.

from uploadNext method it calles onUploadProgress method but does not pass in any parameters

```
xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", onUploadProgress, false);
```

but if you look at onUploadProgress method it takes a parameter (e) what is this e?

```
function onUploadProgress(e) {
    if (e.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = parseInt((e.loaded + totalUploaded) * 100 / totalFileLength);
        var bar = document.getElementById('bar');
        bar.style.width = percentComplete + '%';
        bar.innerHTML = percentComplete + ' % complete';
    } else {
        debug('unable to compute');
    }
}
```

Thank so much for helping me lean

Answer (score 1):

when you define enctype:"multipart/form-data" in form then MutlipartResolver on server side resolve the multipart request.

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
  <property name="defaultEncoding"><value>utf-8</value></property>
</bean>
```

**Js method :**

```
function uploadFile(thisVar,fileName){ 

        var msg='',params="fileName="+fileName;

        var fileContent = new FormData();
        fileContent.append(fileName,thisVar.files[0]);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            enctype:"multipart/form-data",
            url: "addCoupons?"+params,
            data: fileContent,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            beforeSend: function() { 
                $(thisVar).parent().toggleClass('fa-upload fa-refresh fa-spin');//.click('false');
            },
            complete:function(){ 
                $(thisVar).parent().toggleClass('fa-upload fa-refresh fa-spin');//.click('true');
            }
        }).done(function(responseText) { 
            //alert('on success '+responseText);

        }).fail(function(){ 
          alert("Error");
       });
    }
```

**On Controller :**

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/addCoupons")
 public  @ResponseBody String insertData(MultipartHttpServletRequest request) //@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file
       {

                CommonsMultipartFile file = (CommonsMultipartFile) 
                      request.getFile(request.getParameter("fileName"));
        }
```